# Get android intent data from javascript service worker

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, progressive-web-apps

I was browsing some days ago and found that there is new API for javascript service worker, that can recieve android intent and fires it like https:/my.app/scancode/details, but i cannot find it now in google search and etc, could u send me link for this API?

Answer (score 0):

- Service Worker API : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API
- AWS Amplify ServiceWorker : https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/prev/build-a-backend/utilities/service-worker/
- Using Service Workers : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Comment: no, man, not this. i have integrated barcode scanner which is broadcasting android.intent.ACTION_DECODE_DATA event and i need to register broadcast listener from my js webpage or in allready builted and good working js service worker, maybe chrome with some api will be registered to listen it and calling fetch or message for sw....

Comment: like vice-versa for https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/intents